# How to set a scene button to reposition the camera to a fixed point?

Tags: javascript, object, camera, aframe, webvr

In a desktop app, my intention is to create a button in the scene in order to reposition the camera and the rest of camera parameters so as to view the scene from a fixed perspective. I did not succeed on that because after I move the scene view with the mouse and keyboard arrows, the button did not work and the scene is not viewed from the fixed perspective I expect.

```js
//FUNCTION
var pared01 = document.querySelector('#cam-rig');
var camera01 = document.querySelector('#head');
function rota90g() {
  camera01.setAttribute('look-controls', 'enabled', 'false');
  pared01.setAttribute('position', '1 0 0');
  pared01.setAttribute('rotation', '0 -90 0');
  camera01.setAttribute('position', '0 1.6 0');
  camera01.setAttribute('rotation', '0 0 0');
  camera01.setAttribute('look-controls', 'enabled', 'true');

}
```

```html
<!--CAMERA-->
<a-entity id="cam-rig" position="0 0 -1" rotation="0 0 0">
  <!-- Camera -->
  <a-camera id="head" camera="active: true" position="0 1.6 0" wasd-controls look-controls cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
  </a-camera>
</a-entity>

<!--BUTTON-->
<a-image class="button" id="flecha_01" src="#flecha01" position="3 -2.2 0" event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; material.color: #ff0000" event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; material.color: #ffffff" onclick="rota90g()">
</a-image>
```

I have tried using code like: "camera01.object3D.position.set(0, 1.6, 0);" but it did not work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: A full and simple runnable example will help people to help you. Glitch is a good option: https://glitch.com/~aframe

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, I found a solution that works. The final button function was:
    function rota00g() {
      camera01.setAttribute('position', '0 1.6 -1');
      camera01.components["look-controls"].pitchObject.rotation.x = THREE.Math.degToRad(0);
      camera01.components["look-controls"].yawObject.rotation.y = THREE.Math.degToRad(0);
    };

The specific numbers can be modified in any way.